# VPN клиент Андроид Java

Tags: java, android, vpn

У меня есть небольшой опыт в разработки приложений но с такой штукой как тунелирование я еще не встречался. И встала такая задача. Нужно сделать приложения которое бы запросом на мой сервер брал список бесплатных впн серверов и после подключился к одному из них. Меня интересует клиентская часть. Как реализовать подключения? какие инструменты может готовое апи нужно использовать? Что посоветуете почитать и куда смотреть?

Answer (score 1):

Вот несколько примеров реализации VPN на андроид. 3 разных протокола.
https://github.com/zodsoft/LightVPN - `PPTP`
https://github.com/mikma/ipsec-android - `IPsec`
https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn - `OpenVPN`